# HttpError 500 - Internal Error when training ML in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am building my trainer package manually with setuptools and upload the distribution (.tar.gz) to a bucket in GCP (as instructed [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/packaging-trainer)). I then created a service account and give ML Engine Developer and Storage Object Admin roles.

I tried to run the trainer package by calling the API from my python code. The code followed exactly what was written [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/training-jobs). However, I received an error message: **HttpError 500 - Internal error encountered**. Unfortunately, the error is too generic that does not allow me to debug and the ML job is not created in the console.

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient import discovery

training_inputs = {'scaleTier': 'STANDARD_1',
    'packageUris': ['gs://mybucket/trainerPackage-0.1.tar.gz'],
    'pythonModule': 'trainer.task',
    'args': ['--data-dir', 'gs://mybucket/data/evaluate_data.csv',
             '--job-dir', 'gs://mybucket/output', 
             '--epochs', '10' 
             ],
    'region': 'asia-east1',
    'jobDir': 'gs://mybucket/output',
    'runtimeVersion': '1.2'}
job_spec = {'jobId':'ml_test', 'trainingInput':training_inputs}

project_name = 'test-proj'
project_id = 'projects/{}'.format(project_name)
credentials_dict = {my_cred_from_json}
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(credentials_dict)
cloudml = discovery.build('ml', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
request = cloudml.projects().jobs().create(body=job_spec,
              parent=project_id)
try:
    response = request.execute()
except Exception as err:
    print('There was an error creating the training job.'
                  ' Check the details:')
    print(err._get_reason())
    print(str(err))
```

Here is the structure of my trainer package:

```
trainerPackage
 - trainer
    - __init__.py
    - task.py
 - setup.py
```

and here is my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
            'tensorflow >= 1.2',
            'pandas >= 0.20.3',
            'numpy >= 1.13.3'
        ]

setup(
      name = 'trainerPackage',
      version = '0.1',
      install_requires = REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
      packages = find_packages(),
      include_package_data = True,
      description = 'This is an example trainer package.'
)
```

I have verified that my trainer code is working fine. It run successfully on local machine and with `gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training`.

Comment: This is a bug. Allow us to investigate.

Comment: Hi @rhaertel80 May I know the ETA for this?

Comment: hi @rhaertel80 Any news on this? or how do I get support from GCP team for this?

Comment: I tried your code, first with the default credentials. Next, I created a service account with "Owner" role and used that private key. Both times the jobs were successfully submitted to the service. Are you still experiencing the problem?